# Java method repeats output incorrectly and too often

Tags: java, output, static-methods, repeat

I was just trying to get suggestions per the course mentor's advice on StackOverflow. I am sorry.

Comment: In `print_average_grade`, wrap the logic to calculate the average and print in a condition that will only do it if the student id of `s` matches `studentId`.

Answer (score 3):

```
/**
 * prints a student’s average grade by student ID
 * @param  (String studentID)/     */    
public static void print_average_grade(String studentID)
{
    // Here, you have studentID passed into the function but you are not using it
    for (Student s : studentList)
    {
        // Use the studentID here!
        if(s.getStudentID().equals(studentID)) {
            double total = s.getGrade1() + s.getGrade2() + s.getGrade3();
            double average = total / 3;
            System.out.println("StudentID# " + studentID + "  " + average);
        }
    }
}
```

Use the `studentID` passed in as an argument, so that you will print out the average grade for the correct student each time.

Comment: Thank you, that was very enlightening and elegant!

Comment: @JenniferChester Take a look at MadProgrammer's answer, his method is definitely the way to go.. Mine is just a quick fix :)

Comment: @Gosu You could make it better by adding a `break` in when you find a matching student (but it does the job ;))

Answer (score 3):

You're using two loops, first you use

```
for (Student s : studentList) {
    print_average_grade(s.getStudentID());
}
```

to call `print_average_grade`, passing it the `studentID`, which you promptly ignore and then loop over all the students, again...

```
public static void print_average_grade(String studentID) {
    for (Student s : studentList) {

        double total = s.getGrade1() + s.getGrade2() + s.getGrade3();
        double average = total / 3;
        System.out.println("StudentID# " + studentID + "  " + average);
    }

}
```

Instead, change your `print_average_grade` method to accept a `Student` and simply calculate the average for said student

```
public static void print_average_grade(Student s) {
    double total = s.getGrade1() + s.getGrade2() + s.getGrade3();
    double average = total / 3;
    System.out.println("StudentID# " + studentID + "  " + average);
}
```

Then in your main, loop, just pass it the `Student` you want...

```
for (Student s : studentList) {
    print_average_grade(s);
}
```

If you "really" need to do this by `id`, then I would write a method which took a `int` value (id) and does the lookup passing back the `Student` object, since you seem to want to do this a few times...(mind you a `Map` would be more useful)

```
public Student getStudentById(int id) {
    Student match = null;
    for (Student s : studentList) {
        if (s.getStudentID() == id) {
            match = s;
            break;
        }
    }
    return match;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the print average method, you are not making use of the student id that is being passed to it to filter the list. You are iterating the whole list and printing average for all each time. But while printing its the student id that was passed to function is being used and the average of all students will be shown against the same id.

Answer (score 1):

In `print_average_grade`, wrap the logic to calculate the average and print in a condition that will only do it if the student id of `s` matches `studentId`.

```
public static void print_average_grade(String studentID) {
  for (Student s : studentList) {
    if (!s.getStudentID().equals(studentID)) continue;
    double total = s.getGrade1() + s.getGrade2() + s.getGrade3();
    double average = total / 3;
    System.out.println("StudentID# " + studentID + " " + average);
  }
}
```

Alternatively, you could create a method to "find" the student with that id, and then pass just that student to `print_average_grade`. Or, you could store students in a `Map<String, Student>`, where the key is the student id, so you could find a student with `map.get(studentID)`.

Answer (score 0):

Changing print_average_grade(String studentID) to print_average_grade(Student student) will solve as below:

```
for (Student s : studentList)
        print_average_grade(s);


public static void print_average_grade(Student student) {
    double total = student.getGrade1() + student.getGrade2()
            + student.getGrade3();
    double average = total / 3;
    System.out.println("StudentID# " + student.getStudentID() + "  "
            + average);
}
```